# Invalid email in Django Password Reset

Tags: django, django-authentication

I am implementing Django Password Reset to send a recovery password link when the user type his/her email id using django.contrib.auth.urls, which works as perfectly.

This is from Django Documentation,

> If the email address provided does not exist in the system, the user is inactive, or has an unusable password, the user will still be redirected to this view but no email will be sent.

My question is,

If I add something like EmailValidation to check if the user typed email exists in the database or not and raise ValidationError, will that be a security problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously, because it will allow a hacker to run brute force to guess emails. And if the password strength of the user is not strong enough, he might use brute force or guesses to forceful login(if there is no other security methods). I would suggest to put a [captcha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA) on reset page as well, to prevent the bots in reset password page.